# Why is my double variable showing nan through adding c++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to print the totalprofit into the output file, but the totalprofit comes out to be nan. The profit variable is fine, and its not turning toward infinity or dividing by 0. I'm simply adding the profit values into a totalprofit. Not sure why its showing me nan.

```
double profit, totalprofit; 

int intsize = 500;

for(int j = 0; j < 372500; j++)
{


  infile>>data;
  tradethis.push_back(data);

  if(j%intsize==0)
  {

    for(int i=1; i<intsize; i++)
      {
          profit=0;
          profit=eurusd.position(i-1)*((tradethis[i]-tradethis[i-1])); //position returns 1000

          totalprofit = totalprofit + profit;

          outdata<<totalprofit<<endl;

          cout<<totalprofit<<endl;

          //pnl.push_back(totalprofit);

          if(profit>0)
          {
              c+=1.0;
              t+=1.0;
          }

          else if(profit<0)
          {
              w+=1.0;
              t+=1.0;
          }

      }
      tradethis.clear();
  }

}
outdata.close();
```

Comment: NaN means "not a number". NaN + 1000 is still NaN.

Answer (score 2):

1. Always initialize your variables

`double profit = 0, totalprofit = 0;`
 A good compiler would warn on that.

2. Declare the variables where you need it, not on top. `profit` does not need an early declaration.

Comment: I tried that... I also tried to convert the totalprofit to a string, and then print it, but it still doesnt give me the answers. Its a pretty simple code, I'm not sure what the problem is

Comment: Step it through the debugger.